# Как сделать набор форм из двух связанных моделей в django?

Tags: django, form, forms, формы

Есть две модели, вопрос и ответы.
Мне нужно сделать набор форм и определить ему собственную валидацию. 
 С валидацией нет проблем. Проблема с созданием набора. Я почитал доку, прогуглил уже много.
Я сделал добавление вопросов и ответов в админке. Теперь мне нужно:

- Выводить юзеру тест из случайных нескольких вопросов, на каждый
  только один правильный ответ(`RadioSelect()` юзать).
- Проверять на все ли ответил и правильно ли ответил.

Как я понимаю, надо создать форму для одного вопроса с ответами, и сделать набор форм из этой формы. Но туда еще и данные начальные надо запихать(т.е. вопрос и ответы).
Проблема только с созданием формы. Не могу понять как сделать. Подскажите что куда смотреть.
**Модели**:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField("Вопрос:")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField("Дата создания вопроса",
                                        auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField("Активен ли вопрос", default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Вопрос"
        verbose_name_plural = "Вопросы"


class Answers(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name="Вопрос: ")
    answer = models.CharField("Ответ:", max_length=250)
    correctly = models.BooleanField("Правильный ответ", default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```